# Заголовок connection keep-alive в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Нужно ли в ASP.NET вручную добавлять заголовок Connection со значением keep-alive, чтобы не терять соединение с сайтом? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, этого не требуется. Управление HTTP-соединениями - это задача IIS, а не ASP.NET.

По поводу же "как это сделать" - вот документация из MSDN: [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183(v=ws.10).aspx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)